# Multiple primary keys in table using adonis migration / nodejs

Tags: node.js, migration, adonis.js

I have this table:

```
BookUnit
-------------------
id PK
unit PK
sequence PK
book_id FK
```

So, i can have records with data:

```
id: 1
unit: 1
sequence: 1

id: 2
unit: 1
sequence: 2
```

but **i can't have more than one repetead**:

> ```
> id: 3
> unit: 1
> sequence: 2
> ```

So, i need to create a composed primary key with id,sequence and unit.

I try this way:

```
class BookUnitSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('book_unit', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('book_id').references('id').inTable('books').notNullable()
      table.integer('unit').notNullable().primary()
      table.integer('sequence').notNullable().primary()
      table.string('description')
      table.integer('qt_question')
      table.boolean('status').defaultTo(false)
      table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('book_unit')
  }
}
```

But i'm getting:

> error: multiple primary keys for table "book_unit" are not allowed

I don't find in docs example with more than one primary key...

Comment: You can't create multiple primary keys, but you can create multiple foreign keys

Answer (score 5):

you also use primary

```
table.primary(['unit','sequence'])
```

it's work for me 
 
More information visit [knex.js](https://knexjs.org/#Schema-primary)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, i fixed using:

```
table.unique(['unit', 'sequence'])
```